# Integration tests for Http4s Client/Resource

Tags: scala, http4s, cats-effect

I'm implementing a [Vault client](https://github.com/ist-dsi/scala-vault) in Scala using Http4s client.

And I'm now starting to write integration tests. So far I have this:

```
abstract class Utils extends AsyncWordSpec with Matchers {
  implicit override def executionContext = ExecutionContext.global
  implicit val timer: Timer[IO] = IO.timer(executionContext)
  implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(executionContext)

  val vaultUri = Uri.unsafeFromString(Properties.envOrElse("VAULT_ADDR", throw IllegalArgumentException))
  val vaultToken = Properties.envOrElse("VAULT_TOKEN", throw IllegalArgumentException)
  val clientResource = BlazeClientBuilder[IO](global)
    .withCheckEndpointAuthentication(false)
    .resource

  def usingClient[T](f: VaultClient[IO] => IO[Assertion]): Future[Assertion] = {
    clientResource.use { implicit client =>
      f(new VaultClient[IO](vaultUri, vaultToken))
    }.unsafeToFuture()
  }
}
```

Then my tests look like this (just showing one test):

```
class SysSpec extends Utils {
  "The auth endpoint" should {
    "successfully mount an authentication method" in {
      usingClient { client =>
        for {
          result <- client.sys.auth.create("test", AuthMethod(
            "approle", "some nice description", config = TuneOptions(defaultLeaseTtl = 60.minutes)
          ))
        } yield result should be (())
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This approach works, however it doesn't feel right. For each test I'm opening the connection (`clientResource.use`) and recreating the `VaultClient`.

Is there a way for me to reuse the same connection and client for all the tests in SysSpec.

Please note these are integration tests and not unit tests.

Comment: `client.sys.auth.create` returns `IO[Unit]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I could come up with.

```scala
abstract class Utils extends AsyncWordSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {
  implicit override def executionContext = ExecutionContext.global
  implicit val timer: Timer[IO] = IO.timer(executionContext)
  implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(executionContext)

  val (httpClient, finalizer) = BlazeClientBuilder[IO](global)
    .withCheckEndpointAuthentication(false)
    .resource.allocated.unsafeRunSync()
  override protected def afterAll(): Unit = finalizer.unsafeRunSync()

  private implicit val c = httpClient
  val client = new VaultClient[IO](uri"http://[::1]:8200", "the root token fetched from somewhere")
}
```

Then the tests just use the client directly:

```scala
class SysSpec extends Utils {
  "The auth endpoint" should {
    "successfully mount an authentication method" in {
      client.sys.auth.create("test", AuthMethod(
        "approle", "some nice description",
        config = TuneOptions(defaultLeaseTtl = 60.minutes))
      ).map(_ shouldBe ()).unsafeToFuture()
    }
  }
}
```

My two main problems with this approach are the two `unsafeRunSync`s in the code. The first one is to create the client and the second one to clean the resource. However it is a much better approach then repeatedly creating and destroy the client.

I would also like not to use the `unsafeToFuture` but that would require ScalaTest to support Cats-Effect directly.